# Closing side-nav on clicking router link for small devices

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-routing

I am using `side-nav` component in my project for routing between the components,which looks like this:

[image]

Here i am facing an issue.The `side-nav` appears as `toggle-menu` for mobile devices as shown in the image. When i `click/select` any `list-item (ex Home)` .The `side-nav` should close.But it is not.

> I have asked it  once,  still no appropriate solution.

Here is the stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ll5i7-7ggkph?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by

- providing a reference to `mat-sidenav` as `<mat-sidenav #snav`
- Using this reference to `toggle` or `close` the `mat-sidenav`, from where you want this side nav to close. Say, from an anchor click as 
   `<a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav" (click)="snav.toggle()" >`
- You can use `(click)="snav.toggle()"` or `(click)="snav.close()"`

**Code :**

```
<mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'" 
[fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav" 
          (click)="snav.toggle()" >{{nav}}</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
```

**[Stackblitz Demo showing closing of side nav on clicking on item-link](https://angular-close-side-nav-on-button-click.stackblitz.io)**

**Application Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-close-side-nav-on-button-click?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html

**Update 1 :**

- Side Nav will close only in mobile mode, and not in desktop mode.

  **[Code attached in Question](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-closing-side-nav-in-mobile?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.html)**

Comment: Let me try your answer.

Comment: In your code the `toggle-menu (i,e side-nav)` is already present for larger screens also. I want to make `toggle-menu` only for small devices.

Comment: i just took a small demo from the stackblitz and implemented the close functionlaity for the sidenav.

Comment: I have already asked this question twice still i didn't got any solution...:)

Comment: I have already seen all these DEMO's . My issues is little different please see the full question once..:)

Comment: Okay. let me see something and will try implementing in your stackblitz example.

Comment: @Empty_Soul see the updated answer according to your stackblitz. Now closing in mobile mode only.

Comment: Thanks a lot...:)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar could you pls open github repo for the demo. somewhere im lost. but couldn't able to find it.

Comment: @worstCoder please check this link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-close-side-nav-on-button-click?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html, as this link contains code as well. Project Structure is visible under files section in Stackblitz.

Comment: yes i did as it is. but only difference is am adding routerlink and router-outlet. but it doesnt show anything.

Comment: `├───app
│   └───component
│       ├───router-1
│       ├───router-2
│       └───myMenu
───app.component.html
───app.component.ts
───app.module.ts
├───assets
└───environments`

Comment: @AbhishekKumar thats actually my folder structure. (sry about alignment)

Comment: please download the code and try making changes on the local machine. Search the google for the problems and May be on local you can get the code running. This code is running so have to add your router code to integrate. Integrate on local to get successful execution of code.

Comment: hey. my bad. its my mistake only. now found and resolve it thanks

Comment: @worstCoder don’t thank me, its you that have made it right. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but consider this:

```
    <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
      <mat-sidenav #drawer fixedInViewport="true" [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
        [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
        <mat-toolbar color="primary" style="margin-top:30px;"> Business</mat-toolbar>

        <mat-nav-list >
          <mat-list-item (click)="select('home')"  >
            <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
            <span matLine>Home</span>
          </mat-list-item>

          <mat-list-item (click)="select('person')" >
            <mat-icon matListIcon>person</mat-icon>
            <span matLine>Customers</span>
          </mat-list-item>

          <mat-list-item (click)="select('employees')" >
            <mat-icon matListIcon>group_work</mat-icon>
            <span matLine>employees</span>
          </mat-list-item>

          <mat-list-item (click)="select('business')">
            <mat-icon matListIcon>business</mat-icon>
            <span matLine>Business</span>
          </mat-list-item>

        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
          <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
          </button>

        </mat-toolbar>

        <div class="ylb-app-content">
          <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

and in the ts add a function like:

```
select(option: string) {
  // handle it
  this.viewChild.toggle();
}
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked for me.

Comment: What did it say or do?

Answer (score 0):

In your Demo,
I added following content in component.ts file and it is working fine.
I took reference of element in ts file and called toggle method.
Please try this and let me know if it is working fine or not.

```
export class SidenavResponsiveExample {
    @ViewChild('drawer') drawer;

    selected(option: string) {
        this.drawer.toggle();
    }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ll5i7-a6je6c

Comment: Onclick the list-item for ex `home`. The side-nav is hiding fine. but i want to hide it only for small devices.

Comment: Do you want to keep it open for small devices ? or you do not want to open the menu itself for small devices ?